# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime Parse(System.String)' method

Tags: linq-to-entities

I'm a newbie to Linq and the below query keeps returning "does not recognize System.DateTime" error.  I've tried Parse and Convert and neither works.  Here's my query:

mrcEntities context = GetContext();

```
        var query = from c in context.tblClients
                    where (c.FirstName != null || c.LastName != null)
                       && c.EligibilityDate >= DateTime.Parse("10/01/2011")
                       && c.EligibilityDate <= DateTime.Parse("04/30/2012")
                      orderby c.ClientID
                    select new
                    {
                        ClientID = c.ClientID,
                        FirstName = c.FirstName,
                        LastName = c.LastName,
                        MiddleName = c.MidName,
                        SSN = c.SSN,
                        DOB = c.DOB,
                        Sex = c.Gender,
                        Ethnic = c.EthnicCode
                    };

        clientRowCnt = query.Count();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

It's because EF can't turn DateTime.Parse into a function available on the store.  If you replace the results of the calls to DateTime.Parse() and use those variables in your query it should work fine.

```
var from = DateTime.Parse("10/01/2011");
var to = DateTime.Parse("04/30/2012");
var query = from c in context.tblClients
                    where (c.FirstName != null || c.LastName != null)
                       && c.EligibilityDate >= from
                       && c.EligibilityDate <= to
                      orderby c.ClientID
                    select new
                    {
                        ClientID = c.ClientID,
                        FirstName = c.FirstName,
                        LastName = c.LastName,
                        MiddleName = c.MidName,
                        SSN = c.SSN,
                        DOB = c.DOB,
                        Sex = c.Gender,
                        Ethnic = c.EthnicCode
                    };

        clientRowCnt = query.Count();
```

Answer (score 3):

Just parse the date outside of your query. Or use the constructor to create the date without even parsing it (you know the values already it seems.

```
DateTime start = DateTime.Parse("10/01/2011");
DateTime emd = DateTime.Parse(04/30/2012);

var query = from c.....
```

Or use:

```
DateTime start = new DateTime(2011, 10, 01);
DateTime end = new DateTime(2012, 04, 30);

var query = from c.....
```

You can also safely parse the string in the projection part of your query, since that part is executed on the client side after the data has been retrieved. so

```
var query = from c...
select
    new {
        EligibilityDate = Datetime.Parse(c.EligibilityDate)
    }
```

It's only when the parsed value is needed in the selection criteria, when you need to supply it as a DateTime value.

A better solution, by far, is to fix the database schema, or even just add a calculated column to the existing schema which does the parsing on the server and exposes the correct Typed column.

Comment: What if the DateTime.Parse depended on "from c"?
Eg. DateTime.Parse(c.date)?

Comment: I'm sorry could you elaborate? Wouldn't the "does not recognize method" occur?