# Linq to Entities does not recognize the method System.DateTime.. and cannot translate this into a store expression

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a problem that has taken me weeks to resolve and I have not been able to.

I have a class where I have two methods. The following is supposed to take the latest date from database. That date represents the latest payment that a customer has done to "something":

```
public DateTime getLatestPaymentDate(int? idCustomer)
{
    DateTime lastDate;

    lastDate = (from fp in ge.Payments
                from cst in ge.Customers
                from brs in ge.Records.AsEnumerable()
                where (cst.idCustomer == brs.idCustomer && brs.idHardBox == fp.idHardbox
                       && cst.idCustomer == idCustomer)
                select fp.datePayment).AsEnumerable().Max();

    return lastDate;
}//getLatestPaymentDate
```

And here I have the other method, which is supposed to call the previous one to complete a Linq query and pass it to a Crystal Report:

```
//Linq query to retrieve all those customers'data who have not paid their safebox(es) annuity in the last year.
public List<ReportObject> GetPendingPayers()
{
    List<ReportObject> defaulterCustomers;

      defaulterCustomers = (from c in ge.Customer
                            from br in ge.Records
                            from p in ge.Payments

                            where (c.idCustomer == br.idCustomer
                                   && br.idHardBox == p.idHardBox)

                            select new ReportObject
                            {
                                CustomerId = c.idCustomer,
                                CustomerName = c.nameCustomer,
                                HardBoxDateRecord = br.idHardRecord,
                                PaymentDate = getLatestPaymentDate(c.idCustomer),
                            }).Distinct().ToList();
}//GetPendingPayers
```

No compile error is thrown here, but when I run the application and the second method tries to call the first one in the field `PaymentDate` the error mentioned in the header occurs:

`Linq to Entities does not recognize the method System.DateTime.. and cannot translate this into a store expression`

Please anybody with an useful input that put me off from this messy error? Any help will be appreciated !

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at these other questions :

[LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259567/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method)

[LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime Parse(System.String)' method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10384862/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-system-datetime-parsesystem-str)

Basically, you cannot use a value on the C# side and translate it into SQL. The first question offers a more thorough explanation ; the second offers a simple solution to your problem.

**EDIT :**

Simply put : the EF is asking the SQL server to perform the `getLatestPaymentDate` method, which it has no clue about. You need to execute it on the program side.

Simply perform your query first, put the results into a list and then do your `Select` on the in-memory list :

```
 List<ReportObject> defaulterCustomers;

  var queryResult = (from c in ge.Customer
                        from br in ge.Records
                        from p in ge.Payments

                        where (c.idCustomer == br.idCustomer
                               && br.idHardBox == p.idHardBox)).Distinct().ToList();

defaulterCustomers = from r in queryResult
                     select new ReportObject
                        {
                            CustomerId = r.idCustomer,
                            CustomerName = r.nameCustomer,
                            HardBoxDateRecord = r.idHardRecord,
                            PaymentDate = getLatestPaymentDate(r.idCustomer),
                        }).Distinct().ToList();
```

I don't have access to your code, obviously, so try it out and tell me if it works for you!
You'll end up with an in-memory list

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your inputs, but I really could not make this work yet. You said that the second question provided by you was the simplest but I do not get how it would actually solve my problem due to I already declared a variable of DateTime type and parsed it to a hypothetical date and still does not work. Could you explain this a little more to me? I would appreciate it so much !

Comment: Of course! Simply put : the `getLatestPaymentDate` has no SQL equivalent. I'll edit my answer to be more explicit in what you could do.